# How can React Native be used to interface with an Amazon Connect Contact Control Panel (CCP)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-connect

Since I couldn't find the answer after hours of searching, my first attempt was to load a [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) in React Native and point it to a custom CCP page hosted on my own server using [Amazon Connect Streams](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams). This is the method which seems well documented, but it is intended for desktops. It works great in Firefox on desktop and mobile (Android). When I try it in Chrome or the React Native WebView, it fails.

Developer tools on the desktop version of Chrome gives this error: `Refused to display '<URL>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` Obviously, I don't have control over Amazon's `X-Frame-Options` but I don't think that's really the main problem. The other error shown in the console is: `amazon-connect.js:204 [2020-07-14T22:12:32.258Z] [WARN]: ACK_TIMEOUT occurred, attempting to pop the login page if not already open. WARN @ amazon-connect.js:204 amazon-connect.js:205 [2020-07-14T22:12:32.262Z] [ERROR]: ACK_TIMEOUT occurred but we are unable to open the login popup.` I don't know what to do about this one.

I've also looked at the [AWS.Connect API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Connect.html), but it only seems to allow the customer side of a connection.

Has this been done before? If so, could someone give the broad strokes of it? I want to create an app which can connect to the Amazon CCP and maintain the connection so the agent can get an alert as soon as a chat attempt comes in.

Alternative solutions would be appreciated as well.

**Update**: There is a library from Amazon called [`amazon-connect-chatjs`](https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-chatjs) which looks promising, but I'm not sure if it will allow for the agent side of the chat session. I'm reading about it now.

Comment: were you able to find any solution?

Comment: @FurqanKhan No. I gave up for the time being but I would like to revisit this in the future. If you find something, please share it.